# How do you get the number keypad to come up in an iPhone web app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, qwerty

On a web page that is to be displayed on an iPhone, is there a way to get the number pad to come up when the user taps in the field, instead of the qwerty keypad?

[This guy says here's how to do it](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1197-Defaulting-To-The-Numeric-Keyboard-On-The-iPhone.htm), but as of 2.0, this "feature" was disabled.

I'm guessing there's some fancy javascript to employ to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the HTML5 `number` input type, the keyboard will default to showing numbers. It's not the number-only keyboard, but it's a bit better than just `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this used to be possible by including the word "zip" in your text field's name attribute. Unfortunately, Apple seems to have removed this in 2.0 and later. I suggest you file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can make calls from JavaScript to Objective-C and then display what ever you want.  If you want a framework to help you out you could check out QuickConnectiPhone.  It is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickconnect/.

You could also check out http://tetontech.wordpress.com.  This is the develpment blog for QuickConnect.  It has some example code in addition to that which is included in the sourceforge download.